# Replace string with blank from code line

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace the string from any code line with blank, so i need a regular expression that can replace the string from code line for better understanding i am providing a example.

```
else if (srcdtauc.indexOf("(CALL ") != -1) //this should be replaced as 

else if (srcdtauc.indexOf("") != -1)
```

thankyou.

i still have not got the regular expression. i want a regular expression that replace the content between "" with blank string thats it.

Comment: @milan nothing a line of source that is to be manipulated.

Comment: This code `srcdtauc.indexOf("") != -1` is always `true` You can remove the if expression completely.

Comment: @Peter i think i was not able to describe the question actually i want to replace the string between quotes by "".

Comment: In the string `srcdtauc` or in the code?

Comment: @Peter any position of string should be replaced by ""(blank string).

Comment: So you want to delete `(CALL ` from the string? So `(CALL ME)` becomes `ME)` ?

Comment: I think you all misunderstand rahulsri. If I am not completely wrong, he wants to treat his complete code as a string and then replace some inner strings (which means, everything in double quotes) by blank strings. I don't think it's that hard to understand even if it could have been better articulated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following regexp:

```
((\\.|(?!("|\\)).)*)
```

In Java:

```
String myRegexp = "\"((\\\\.|(?!(\"|\\\\)).)*)\"";
```

Comment: thanks for understand the problem..i have used your regex by modifying as "((\\.|(?!(\"|\\)).)*)" but it is still not working.

Comment: @rahulsri It looks like you interpreted my quotes (`"`) as containers but they are part of the regexp! If you're writing it into a string in Java it would look like `String myRegexp = "\"((\\\\.|(?!("|\\\\)).)*)\"";`.

Comment: yeah it works by making slight modification String myRegexp = "\"((\\\\.|(?!(\"|\\\\)).)*)\"";

Comment: Oh, you're right, it should have been `String myRegexp = "\"((\\\\.|(?!(\"|\\\\)).)*)\"";`.. now it's correct. (It's still the same regex as in the answer so if it works, you could accept it)